# On Windows 11 is there a way to exclude folders from recommended items

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11

Some folder, items in my developer drives, I never want to show up in Start menu recommended items. Is there a way to exclude paths from consideration?

Comment: You can right click on the item and remove from list.  I am not sure if any method is permanent any more.

Answer (score 2):

The Windows Start Menu search is dependent upon the Windows
search indexing.

You may exclude folders from Windows search using
the button "Add an excluded folder" which is found in:

- Windows 10 :

  - *Settings > Search > Searching Windows*.
  - *Settings > Search > Searching Windows > Advanced indexing options > Modify*
- Windows 11 :
  *Settings > Privacy & security > Searching Windows*.

Comment: On my computer (Windows 11 Home, version 23H2), the paths are _Settings_ > **_Privacy & security_** > _Searching Windows_ > ....

Comment: @Jesper: Thank you - I updated the answer.